# Flatten Dictionary with Helm

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Is there a way to flatten a dictionary with helm? I want to provide environment variables to the application from the chart by flattening a YAML config located in values.yaml. The config can look like. (Not Actual)

```yaml
config:
 server:
  port: 3333
 other:
  setting:
    name: test
```

And would like to provide environment variables as

```yaml
- name: CONFIG_SERVER_PORT
  value: 3333
- name: CONFIG_OTHER_SETTING_NAME
  value: test
```

I have considered using Kubernetes config maps but this would mean deploying slightly different instances of the app with random release names so that the config is not overwritten. 
This library https://github.com/jeremywohl/flatten provides a way to flatten a `map[string]interface{}` with delimeters. Is there a way to provide a custom pipe for helm that uses the library or another way to flatten the config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything like that built in. [Sprig](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) provides most of the useful functions for helm templates but the [dict functions](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) just cover the primitives.

You could `define` a [named template](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/) that does the business and recurses down the config dict/map. Then `include` the template where needed:

```
{{- define "recurseFlattenMap" -}}
{{- $map := first . -}}
{{- $label := last . -}}
{{- range $key, $val := $map -}}
  {{- $sublabel := list $label $key | join "_" | upper -}}
  {{- if kindOf $val | eq "map" -}}
    {{- list $val $sublabel | include "recurseFlattenMap" -}}
  {{- else -}}
- name: {{ $sublabel | quote }}
  value: {{ $val | quote }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Passing the `config` data in is a little complex here, via a `list` that is then separated back out into `$map` and `$label`. This is due to templates only accepting a single variable [scope](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#setting-the-scope-of-a-template).

```
env: {{ list .Values.config "CONFIG" | include "recurseFlattenMap" | nindent 2 }}
```

With the example values:

```
config:
  server:
    port: 3333
  first: astr
  other:
    setting:
      name: test
```

Results in

```
$ helm template . 
---
# Source: so61280873/templates/config.yaml
env: 
  - name: "CONFIG_FIRST" 
    value: "astr"
  - name: "CONFIG_OTHER_SETTING_NAME" 
    value: "test"
  - name: "CONFIG_SERVER_PORT" 
    value: "3333"
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. You might be able to implement this in pure Gotpl with some of the Sprig functions and a lot of local variables but ... don't. You cannot add custom functions to Helm without recompiling it. Just use the native format directly.

Comment: Is there a way then to write the subset of .Values on a yaml file and mount the file to a volume?

Comment: Yes, sprig has a toJson function (JSON is a subset of YAML) so you can use that in a configmap, then mount that configmap as a volume (can also use a secret, same difference).

Comment: Yes but i was trying to avoid config maps. The app can be configured to expose a public API or a private API. The private API is to be run as a sidecar available only to specific micro-services. If micro-service A wants a different config of the private API compared to micro-service B then in the end, with a few more deployments, there is a messy config list in kubernetes without knowing which config is for what side-car. Is there a way to mount a the file without a kubernetes resource? e.g 

```data:
 | {{toYaml .Value.config}}
```

Comment: or rather without config maps but directly in the pod with the file data

Comment: Configmaps and secrets are how you expose config data as files to a pod. If you want to do that thing, then you need to use one of those (or, I guess, write your own CSI plugin).

Answer (score 0):

probably not perfect:

```
{{- range $key, $value := (regexReplaceAll ":\n(  )+" (toYaml .Values) "_" | fromYaml) }}
{{ printf "- %s: %s" $key $value }}
{{- end }}
```

where `.Values` had the form

```
values:
- key:
    subKey: value
- key
    subKey2: value2
```

and I wanted

```
- key_subkey: value
- key2_subKey2: value2
```

specifically this came from using helmfile to manage several separate helm charts into one orchestrated command wanting to collapse the environment values into a configmap chart such that pods could envFrom.configMapRef to load the environment configuration in the helmfile as environment variables

Answer (score -1):

The question you are asking is possible. dont have sources near by.
but try something like this.

```
// chart

apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ template "name" . }}          
          command: [{{ range $i, $e := .Values.container.command }}{{ if $i }}, {{$e|quote}}{{else}}{{$e|quote}}{{end}}{{end}}]          
          env:
          {{- range .Values.container.env }}
            - name: {{ .name }}
              value: "{{ .value }}"
          {{- end }}


// values

container:  
  command: ["cmd", "sub_cmd", "sub_sub_cmd"]    
  env:
      - name: CONFIG_SERVER_PORT
      value: 3333
      - name: CONFIG_OTHER_SETTING_NAME
      value: test
```

Comment: Also while it's entirely unrelated, the better way to do the `command` setting is `command: {{ .Values.command | toJson }}` :)